# Anisble hosts alias not working

Tags: ansible

Im trying to rename my host list file from IP addresses to aliases but for some reason when I run my playbooks i get the below error.

> fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unable to open shell. Please see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#unable-to-open-shell", "rc": 255}

here is a sample of the alias in the host file.

```
test ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.1
```

Im using ansible version 2.3.0

Below is the output from the debug. in the debug  I named the host BWS_DRUN_1921

> 14580 1503500046.84187: Loading CacheModule 'memory' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/cache/memory.py
>    14580 1503500046.94408: Loading CallbackModule 'default' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py
>   Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/**init**.pyc
>    14580 1503500046.94541: Loading CallbackModule 'actionable' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/actionable.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500046.94585: Loading CallbackModule 'context_demo' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/context_demo.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500046.94625: Loading CallbackModule 'debug' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/debug.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500046.94649: Loading CallbackModule 'default' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500046.94723: Loading CallbackModule 'dense' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/dense.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.01864: Loading CallbackModule 'foreman' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/foreman.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02089: Loading CallbackModule 'hipchat' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/hipchat.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02131: Loading CallbackModule 'jabber' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/jabber.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02154: Loading CallbackModule 'json' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/json.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02200: Loading CallbackModule 'junit' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/junit.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02226: Loading CallbackModule 'log_plays' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/log_plays.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02269: Loading CallbackModule 'logentries' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/logentries.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02306: Loading CallbackModule 'logstash' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/logstash.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02411: Loading CallbackModule 'mail' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/mail.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02439: Loading CallbackModule 'minimal' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02462: Loading CallbackModule 'oneline' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/oneline.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02487: Loading CallbackModule 'osx_say' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/osx_say.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02516: Loading CallbackModule 'profile_tasks' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02545: Loading CallbackModule 'selective' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/selective.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02567: Loading CallbackModule 'skippy' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/skippy.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02609: Loading CallbackModule 'slack' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02703: Loading CallbackModule 'syslog_json' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/syslog_json.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02895: Loading CallbackModule 'timer' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/timer.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
>    14580 1503500047.02940: Loading CallbackModule 'tree' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/tree.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)

PLAYBOOK: test.yml ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in test.yml
 14580 1503500047.02996: in VariableManager get_vars()
 14580 1503500047.03297: Loading FilterModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py
 14580 1503500047.04542: Loading FilterModule 'ipaddr' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/ipaddr.py
 14580 1503500047.04632: Loading FilterModule 'json_query' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/json_query.py
 14580 1503500047.04659: Loading FilterModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py
 14580 1503500047.04687: Loading FilterModule 'split' from /home/khibiny/filter_plugins/split.py
 14580 1503500047.04847: Loading TestModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/core.py
 14580 1503500047.04872: Loading TestModule 'files' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/files.py
 14580 1503500047.04892: Loading TestModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/mathstuff.py
 14580 1503500047.05376: done with get_vars()
 14580 1503500047.05509: in VariableManager get_vars()
 14580 1503500047.05558: Loading FilterModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05572: Loading FilterModule 'ipaddr' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/ipaddr.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05584: Loading FilterModule 'json_query' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/json_query.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05597: Loading FilterModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05610: Loading FilterModule 'split' from /home/khibiny/filter_plugins/split.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05637: Loading TestModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05650: Loading TestModule 'files' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/files.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05662: Loading TestModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.05749: done with get_vars()

PLAY [District Switches Fact Check] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 14580 1503500047.06815: Loading StrategyModule 'linear' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py
 14580 1503500047.07030: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
 14580 1503500047.07052: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
 14580 1503500047.07065: building list of next tasks for hosts
 14580 1503500047.07076: getting the next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07090: done getting next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07104:  ^ task is: TASK: meta (flush_handlers)
 14580 1503500047.07117:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=1, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 14580 1503500047.07129: done building task lists
 14580 1503500047.07139: counting tasks in each state of execution
 14580 1503500047.07151: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
        num_setups: 0
        num_tasks: 1
        num_rescue: 0
        num_always: 0
 14580 1503500047.07163: advancing hosts in ITERATING_TASKS
 14580 1503500047.07174: starting to advance hosts
 14580 1503500047.07186: getting the next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07199: done getting next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07211:  ^ task is: TASK: meta (flush_handlers)
 14580 1503500047.07223:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=1, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 14580 1503500047.07234: done advancing hosts to next task
META: ran handlers
 14580 1503500047.07681: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
 14580 1503500047.07695: results queue empty
 14580 1503500047.07705: checking for any_errors_fatal
 14580 1503500047.07719: done checking for any_errors_fatal
 14580 1503500047.07729: checking for max_fail_percentage
 14580 1503500047.07740: done checking for max_fail_percentage
 14580 1503500047.07751: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
 14580 1503500047.07761: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
 14580 1503500047.07772: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
 14580 1503500047.07798: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
 14580 1503500047.07812: building list of next tasks for hosts
 14580 1503500047.07823: getting the next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07837: done getting next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07850:  ^ task is: TASK: Gather IOS facts
 14580 1503500047.07861:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 14580 1503500047.07873: done building task lists
 14580 1503500047.07884: counting tasks in each state of execution
 14580 1503500047.07896: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
        num_setups: 0
        num_tasks: 1
        num_rescue: 0
        num_always: 0
 14580 1503500047.07908: advancing hosts in ITERATING_TASKS
 14580 1503500047.07918: starting to advance hosts
 14580 1503500047.07929: getting the next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07942: done getting next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500047.07954:  ^ task is: TASK: Gather IOS facts
 14580 1503500047.07965:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 14580 1503500047.07976: done advancing hosts to next task
 14580 1503500047.07993: getting variables
 14580 1503500047.08003: in VariableManager get_vars()
 14580 1503500047.08056: Loading FilterModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08070: Loading FilterModule 'ipaddr' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/ipaddr.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08082: Loading FilterModule 'json_query' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/json_query.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08095: Loading FilterModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08109: Loading FilterModule 'split' from /home/khibiny/filter_plugins/split.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08138: Loading TestModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08150: Loading TestModule 'files' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/files.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08162: Loading TestModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14580 1503500047.08266: done with get_vars()
 14580 1503500047.08293: done getting variables
 14580 1503500047.08305: sending task start callback, copying the task so we can template it temporarily
 14580 1503500047.08317: done copying, going to template now
 14580 1503500047.08330: done templating
 14580 1503500047.08340: here goes the callback...

TASK [Gather IOS facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/khibiny/test.yml:17
 14580 1503500047.08377: sending task start callback
 14580 1503500047.08388: entering _queue_task() for BWS_DRUN_1921/ios_facts
 14580 1503500047.08400: Creating lock for ios_facts
 14580 1503500047.08559: worker is 1 (out of 1 available)
 14580 1503500047.08693: exiting _queue_task() for BWS_DRUN_1921/ios_facts
 14580 1503500047.08724: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
 14580 1503500047.08738: waiting for pending results...
 14587 1503500047.09159: running TaskExecutor() for BWS_DRUN_1921/TASK: Gather IOS facts
 14587 1503500047.09252: in run() - task bcaec527-b1b5-ad9c-5f4c-000000000023
 14587 1503500047.09329: calling self._execute()
 14587 1503500047.09660: Loading FilterModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.09692: Loading FilterModule 'ipaddr' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/ipaddr.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.09710: Loading FilterModule 'json_query' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/json_query.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.09727: Loading FilterModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.09743: Loading FilterModule 'split' from /home/khibiny/filter_plugins/split.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.09794: Loading TestModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.09813: Loading TestModule 'files' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/files.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.09830: Loading TestModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10181: Loading FilterModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10218: Loading FilterModule 'ipaddr' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/ipaddr.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10242: Loading FilterModule 'json_query' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/json_query.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10263: Loading FilterModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10287: Loading FilterModule 'split' from /home/khibiny/filter_plugins/split.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10330: Loading TestModule 'core' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/core.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10353: Loading TestModule 'files' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/files.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10376: Loading TestModule 'mathstuff' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/test/mathstuff.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.10959: Loading Connection 'local' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/local.py
 14587 1503500047.11068: Loading ShellModule 'csh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/csh.py
 14587 1503500047.11136: Loading ShellModule 'fish' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/fish.py
 14587 1503500047.11210: Loading ShellModule 'powershell' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/powershell.py
 14587 1503500047.11252: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py
 14587 1503500047.11301: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.11508: Loading ActionModule 'ios' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/ios.py
 14587 1503500047.11543: starting attempt loop
 14587 1503500047.11564: running the handler
 using connection plugin network_cli
 14587 1503500047.11750: Loading Connection 'persistent' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/persistent.py
 14587 1503500047.11803: Loading ShellModule 'csh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/csh.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.11826: Loading ShellModule 'fish' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/fish.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.11851: Loading ShellModule 'powershell' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/powershell.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.11872: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.11895: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
 14587 1503500047.12006: Loading Connection 'ssh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
 socket_path: /home/khibiny/.ansible/pc/5343f0d88d
open_shell() returned 255  14588 1503500047.84893: Loading Connection 'ssh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
 failed to connect to control socket
 14587 1503500077.91105: handler run complete
 14587 1503500077.91124: attempt loop complete, returning result
 14587 1503500077.91138: _execute() done
 14587 1503500077.91150: dumping result to json
 14587 1503500077.91164: done dumping result, returning
 14587 1503500077.91181: done running TaskExecutor() for BWS_DRUN_1921/TASK: Gather IOS facts [bcaec527-b1b5-ad9c-5f4c-000000000023]
 14587 1503500077.91201: sending task result for task bcaec527-b1b5-ad9c-5f4c-000000000023
 14587 1503500077.91239: done sending task result for task bcaec527-b1b5-ad9c-5f4c-000000000023
 14587 1503500077.91269: WORKER PROCESS EXITING
 14580 1503500077.91394: marking BWS_DRUN_1921 as failed
 14580 1503500077.91440: marking host BWS_DRUN_1921 failed, current state: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 14580 1503500077.91464: ^ failed state is now: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_COMPLETE, fail_state=FAILED_TASKS, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 14580 1503500077.91485: getting the next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500077.91503: host BWS_DRUN_1921 is done iterating, returning
fatal: [BWS_DRUN_1921]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "unable to open shell. Please see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#unable-to-open-shell", 
    "rc": 255
}
 14580 1503500077.91545: no more pending results, returning what we have
 14580 1503500077.91558: results queue empty
 14580 1503500077.91568: checking for any_errors_fatal
 14580 1503500077.91581: done checking for any_errors_fatal
 14580 1503500077.91591: checking for max_fail_percentage
 14580 1503500077.91603: done checking for max_fail_percentage
 14580 1503500077.91613: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
 14580 1503500077.91623: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
 14580 1503500077.91634: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
 14580 1503500077.91648: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
 14580 1503500077.91661: building list of next tasks for hosts
 14580 1503500077.91672: getting the next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500077.91684: host BWS_DRUN_1921 is done iterating, returning
 14580 1503500077.91694: done building task lists
 14580 1503500077.91705: counting tasks in each state of execution
 14580 1503500077.91716: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
        num_setups: 0
        num_tasks: 0
        num_rescue: 0
        num_always: 0
 14580 1503500077.91728: all hosts are done, so returning None's for all hosts
 14580 1503500077.91740: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
 14580 1503500077.91750: results queue empty
 14580 1503500077.91760: checking for any_errors_fatal
 14580 1503500077.91771: done checking for any_errors_fatal
 14580 1503500077.91795: checking for max_fail_percentage
 14580 1503500077.91809: done checking for max_fail_percentage
 14580 1503500077.91823: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
 14580 1503500077.91837: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
 14580 1503500077.91855: getting the next task for host BWS_DRUN_1921
 14580 1503500077.91871: host BWS_DRUN_1921 is done iterating, returning
 14580 1503500077.91886: running handlers

Comment: Can you do some more debugging on your end (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#enable-network-logging)?  You are able to ssh to the target host right?

Comment: Formatted error as quote

Comment: Yes I am able to ssh. The host file works pefect when I use only IP but when I try to add an alias it does not even attempt to establish a connection. It just hangs up as if trying to resolve the hostname.

Comment: I just updated the question with the debug output that I got. In this debug I renamed the alias to BWS_DRUN_1921

Answer (score 0):

`ansible_ssh_host` was deprecated in 2.0.  Use `ansible_host` instead.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups

Comment: Doesnt work with that either. 2.3.0 usually ignores the ssh value